# What is this red/hair loss spot on my cats ear

Tags: cats

My cat is a little over 3. She has a sister who she snuggles with quiet a bit (figured it’s worth mentioning). They are strictly indoors and I keep a very clean home. I noticed this spot on her ear. She doesn’t really seem to be itching or messing with it. My first thought was ring worm but I’ve been told that’s very contagious and I have checked her sister also and have found nothing. Mange/mites was the other thought but I’m not sure that it looks similar to the pictures I have seen. Taking her to the vet is torture enough so I am trying to figure this out without doing that.

One other thing I do want to mention. About 2 weeks ago we moved my boyfriends cat into the home. They are separated still but we are switching their living spaces so they get used to each other scent. I was told something like this could be caused from stress or anxiety, but I’m skeptical. My boyfriends cat was also strictly indoors and I have checked him for spots similar to hers and haven’t found anything either.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Your question has an answer elsewhere so it may be closed. Please have a look into the linked question. If it not help you, then please use the edit button and add more information to your question :) (edit is possible even in closed questions, they will reopen automaticly)

Comment: @Allerleirauh the linked question is about the thin spot on the forehead; this is the back of the ear, and likely would need veterinary attention.

Comment: @AllisonC Thank you! I will undo my vote

Comment: you need to take your cat to the vet for this,it looks like a fungal infection but it can be several other things too allergy,parasites,some type of burn,your vet will know what to look for.